# Keep TinyMCE toolbar when losing focus in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, tinymce, focus

I am using TinyMCE 6 with React and I am creating a plugin to add comments with the selection of the text inside the tiny and I add the comment text from another external component, but when I click on the input of the external component to write it is it loses the focus of tiny so the bar and that selection that I have of the text part inside tiny is hidden.

I already tried to keep the tiny reference and assign the focus again, but the cursor positions it inside tinymce and I can't write to the external input.

Is there a way for me to keep tinymce's toolbar or (focus) while writing to an external input?